# tablet won't permanently keep or remove apps

Tags: storage

I have an 8" android tablet running Android 2.2 (froyo). It works fine, except anything installed will not be retained when you re-start the device. Plus, if I want to remove the one and only app I put on this thing it re-appears after I delete it and re-start the device.

Nothing gets saved and no app gets deleted that is already on there. The app in mention I put on is marble solitaire plus for anyone that wants to know.

I can still find use for the tablet if only I could fix this problem. I have even tried a factory reset and nothing. When I do I get "md5 file error 1. Any ideas would help!

Comment: This question is quite long and rambling. You might get more people to read it if you trim out all the unrelated stuff about your other tablets, try to make it easier to see what the problem is, and add a descriptive title.

Comment: Can you give us the model of the tablet in question? It is very uncommon for an Android tablet to have 2.2 on it unless it is several years old.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a tablet with locked system/data. Kind of like a PC with deep freeze, you can make changes but they are reset after a reboot.

You may have just made an unlucky purchase as many cheapo tablets will do this as a sort of self-protection.

What is likely happening is the system reverts to a copy of the image stored in flash so fixing it is going to require finding wherever the source copy is.

The md5 file error likely means the original copy is corrupt. This is the tough way to learn to avoid cheapo tablets because when something goes wrong you are usually SoL.

Depending on the tablet, you may be able to:

1. unlock the bootloader
2. install custom recovery
3. find a compatible rom and flash it

I'd recommend you just cut your losses, sell it as defective on Craigslist or something similar, and use that money to put towards a decent tablet.